# jQuery .each and setTimeout is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, each

I am trying to get some attar vale from an active slider. I have used each and setTimeout function. Initially, that worked. But after some time the slider stops if I use this code. Note this code is independent of the slider code.

```js
function checkForChanges() {
  $('#ninja-slider ul li').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("ns-show")) {
      //$(this).css("color", "red");
      console.log('yes')
    } else {
      setTimeout(checkForChanges, 3000);
      console.log('no')
    }
  });
}

$(checkForChanges);
```

Comment: `$(checkForChanges)` didn't call target function

Comment: Use `checkForChanges();` instead

Comment: Slider normally work. But when I use this function slider stop working. http://wiregraph.com/dev/ @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Also the console is showing the number of request is too much - https://prnt.sc/lhrw7r @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: That because your calling a recursive function that will not stop until all the `li`'s has the `ns-show` class

Comment: I have used the recursive function as the slider will never stop and I want me data always update as the slide change. So instead of recursive function, is there any other approach I can follow to keep the slider slide and get my value? @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: My goal is to get attr value from the active class only. So {na-show} will not be on all <code>li</code>. It will always exist on one <code>li</code> and as its the active class it always change as the slide change. @ZakariaAcharki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the active slider every 3 seconds so no need for each it could be like :

```
function checkForChanges() {
  //Here is the active li in the slide  
  var active_li = $("#ninja-slider li.ns-show");

  //Get the src of shwon image
  console.log( $("#ninja-slider li.ns-show").find('img').attr('src') );

  setTimeout(checkForChanges, 3000);
}

checkForChanges();
```